# Notepad.exe establishing an outbound TCP over port 1025 from Windows using server to a Teradata server, is this unusual?

Tags: windows-server

We have a situation where a user logged into a Windows Server which primarily runs Tableau established an outbound TCP connection over port 1025 where the destination server is part of a Teradata cluster.

However the tool in question is notepad.exe which seems unusual to me given that there are not very many reasons for it communicate over the internet.

I did notice that prior to the event that a few Datadog agent processes were executed. Could this activity be somehow related to logging activity from Datadog over to the Teradata server?

Comment: are you confident that the process was `notepad.exe` ? is the teradata cluster under your control ? assuming your premise *is* correct, one thought that sprang to mind was that "somehow" the paste buffer was backed up by the tcp socket that (maybe) related to the other activity, and that the user themselves had initiated this connection when they interacted with `notepad.exe` by pasting data into the edit window

Answer (score 1):

Under no circumstances `notepad.exe` by Microsoft can make any network connections, even if you open a file on a network share. In that case the connection will be made by SYSTEM.